# Weird AAAA Record

Tags: domain-name-system

I have been pulled into sorting out a messy domain setup for a client.

Old host that had the DNS still (and hosted mail but not the site). So the client wanted to get their mail away from them as well. I migrated the MX to google and that went fine... and the last step was to move the DNS away.

There were alot of DNS entries for all sorts of things they were never going to use... so most of them were binned by me.

Finally down to the AAAA record and this is an entry I am not familiar with.

The AAAA pointed to ::1 - and this just wouldn't work or propagate.

Can anyone explain what this might have been and if I need it ?

Cheers
Guy

Answer (score 3):

This ::1 is an IPv6 localhost.

That mean it's a record belonging to your old DNS's server.

[To quote another's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/668004/why-is-my-localhost-not-127-0-0-1-but-1-and-what-notation-is-that):

> This is because ping on Windows Vista and newer Windows uses IPv6 by
>   default when available. ::1 is a shortened notation of IPv6 loopback
>   address - equivalent of IPv4 loopback 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Ah thanks - do I need to carry it over ?

Comment: I would not, strange to have put a loopback there

Comment: @Zebbyz if this answer helped you, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

AAAA records are used to specify the IPv6 address of a domain. And `::1` is the IPv6 address of localhost.

The answer to the question whether you need AAAA records is that if you do not already need them, you will probably need them soon. There are already a percentage of users who have more reliable IPv6 connectivity than IPv4, and that percentage is only going to be growing.

But an incorrect AAAA record is worse than no AAAA record at all. An incorrect AAAA record is going to make your domain inaccessible to clients connected through NAT64+DNS64.

An AAAA record pointing to `::1` is in most cases incorrect. Look at the A record for the same domain. If the AAAA record points to `::1` and the A record points to `127.0.0.1`, then it was probably done deliberately.

But if the AAAA record is pointing to `::1` and the A record points to something other than `127.0.0.1`, then the AAAA record is incorrect and will prevent some users from accessing the site. In that case the AAAA record should be changed ASAP or be deleted until you know the correct address to use for your AAAA record.